# How to get key events while running a cpp program in linux?

Tags: c++, console, key, keypress, onkeypress

I have a very simple program which should print all the incremented values till `x` key is pressed. If `x` is pressed then it should exit the program else if `a` is pressed then the iterating integer should reset to 20;

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i;
    while(true){
        
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        if(getchar()==120){
            break;
        }else if(getchar()==122){
            i= 20;
        }
        i++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the problem is `getchar()` halts the loop to get user input. I want to run the while loop endlessly unless `x` is pressed. How should I do it in linux? Is there a cross-platform solution ?

Comment: What exactly is this chapter in your C++ textbook discussing? This can only be done using non-blocking I/O, which is not something that I would expect to find in an introductory C++ textbook, which you must be using to learn C++.

Comment: If you are only using character input, you should probably be fine with `peek()`ing `std::cin` if there is something to read, and then read and process the input from `std::cin` if so. If you also want to use other keys it is highly platform specifc. I would recommend to use a games library that already offers an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how to print i if it doesn't have a value at the start, you should assign 0 or 1 to it. For the not stopping the loop , you probably have to use threads to be able to do that as it requires for you to do 2 things at once.

Comment: Using threads may be a solution, but it is overkill in this simple case. Using a non-blocking function may be easier. Could you add a code sample demonstrating your example?